# How to replace SQL DB with MySQL DB and enable Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I recently published my ASP.net MVC app (Internet Application-template) online. After trying to register as a user and when clicking on the submit-button I receive this error message: "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request."

I contacted my hosting company to ask them what could be the cause. They immediately asked for the Target Framework and database of my application. 

**My ASP.net MVC app specs**

It's an ASP.net MVC 3 application, I use Entity Framework. The Target Framework is 4.0 and my database is SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database.

The hosting company replied to me that they only support MySQL databases (no MS SQL), Target Framework 4.0  and Entity Framework.

**Attempts to solve this problem**

I tried to browse the web (including Stack Overflow) for tutorials on how to integrate MySQL Database in my application, but I fail every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) shows you how to replace the default data storage mechanism for ASP.NET Identity with EntityFramework (SQL client provider) with a MySQL provider.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link for a step by step tutorial.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

Comment: you are asking for an instruction on how to use MySQL on Entity Framework right? It doesn't have to be ASP.NET MVC or WindowsForms to follow the instruction on the link of you are only aiming at the EF part.

Comment: no, i read your "Attempts to solve this problem" part...the link simply shows an example on how to use MySQL in Entity Framework, and of course  you should have your MySQL database ready in order to do the "generate from database" when adding EntityFramework to your project.

Comment: put MVC aside, your goal is to add MySQl EntityFramework, and the method is universal regardless of what type of .NET application you are doing.. just setup a MySQL server on your local machine with schema similar to your local SQL db and follow the instruction on the link.

Comment: This tutorial doesn't work. There is no way to add a provider for MySql that the wizard can use (VS2015)